# Is there a way to draw a arrow inside a circle elegantly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a unit vector in a unit circle.

here is the code

```
vunit = 1/np.sqrt(2)
vec1 = [vunit,vunit]
thetas = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, .05)
coordinates = np.vstack((np.cos(thetas),np.sin(thetas)))

plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
plt.xlim(-3,3)
plt.ylim(-3,3)
plt.scatter(coordinates[0,:],coordinates[1,:],s=.1)
plt.arrow(0, 0, vec1[0], vec1[1], head_width=0.15, color='r')
```

[image]

everything is OK, except the head of arrow is outside the circle.

so, I modify the vec1 ugly

```
vec1 = [vunit-.1,vunit-.1]
```

[image]

the figure looks better and I can modify the vec1 more finely, but the fix seem to be ugly. is there a way to have the arrow inside the circle elegantly

Comment: Do you need to figure out the length of the arrow? In that case the length of the arrow would be your radius, which in this case seems to be 1. I feel like I am missing something though ...

Comment: The arrow consists of 2 pars, head and body. original body is 1 vunit, and the head makes the whole arrow greater than 1 vunit. you may need to know the length of the head part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`length_includes_head=True`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vunit = 1/np.sqrt(2)
vec1 = [vunit,vunit]
thetas = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, .05)
coordinates = np.vstack((np.cos(thetas),np.sin(thetas)))

plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
plt.xlim(-3,3)
plt.ylim(-3,3)
plt.scatter(coordinates[0,:],coordinates[1,:],s=.1)
plt.arrow(0, 0, vec1[0], vec1[1], head_width=0.15, color='r', length_includes_head=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One might use a [`FancyArrowPatch`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch.html) instead of a `FancyArrow` (which is the object produced by `plt.arrow`).
The difference here is marginal, but for other cases, and hence consistency, `FancyArrowPatch` offers a lot of nice features that are not present for `FancyArrow`. One main difference is observed when zooming the plot; the `FancyArrow`'s head is defined in data coordinates, it will hence look skewed when shown in non equal aspect plots.

[image]

So here is the complete code with `FancyArrowPatch`, where we get the head tip at the end coordinate via `shrinkB` argument.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch

vunit = 1/np.sqrt(2)
vec1 = [vunit,vunit]
thetas = np.arange(-np.pi, np.pi, .05)
coordinates = np.vstack((np.cos(thetas),np.sin(thetas)))

plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
plt.xlim(-3,3)
plt.ylim(-3,3)
plt.scatter(coordinates[0,:],coordinates[1,:],s=.1)

arrow = FancyArrowPatch(posA=(0,0), posB=vec1, 
                        arrowstyle='-|>', mutation_scale=20, 
                        shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0, color='r')
plt.gca().add_patch(arrow)

plt.show()
```

[image]